# how To Type Uppercase String in windows phone TextBox Wpf c#

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

how To Type Uppercase String in windows phone TextBox Wpf c#.

I tried it on KeyDown Event.

```
   void TxtPanno_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)  
   {

   TxtPanno.Text = TxtPanno.Text.ToUpper();  //1 code.

   TxtPanno.Text= CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToUpper(TxtPanno.Text); //2 code     

   TxtPanno.Text=Regex.Replace(TxtPanno.Text, "^[A-Z]", m => m.Value.ToUpper());  //3 code. 
   }
```

But Problems is that.

Cursor always go to leftside.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
TxtPanno.Text = TxtPanno.Text.ToUpper(); 
TxtPanno.SelectionStart = TxtPanno.Text.Length;
TxtPanno.SelectionLength = 0;
```

It makes the text uppercase, moves the cursor to the end and selects nothing.

Comment: @ jonas its work :-  TxtPanno.Text.Length-1; 1 Removed.

Comment: Ah, sorry, edited the answed.  Glad it solved your problem. =)

Comment: Did you mean that  `TxtPanno.SelectionStart = TxtPanno.Text.Length;` was the correct answer?

Comment: @ jonas  Actually its not worked as per we need .Type Directly in Caps Word .

Comment: One of the 3 alternatives in the question should make it "Upper case" and the code I provided should move the cursor to the right. 
`TxtPanno.Text = TxtPanno.Text.ToUpper();  //1 code.
TxtPanno.SelectionStart = TxtPanno.Text.Length-1;
 TxtPanno.SelectionLength = 0;` should work. What happens when you try that?

Comment: it through Error TxtPanno.Text.Length-1.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to replace text,instead you should apply styles like this

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="CharacterCasing" Value="Upper"/>
</Style>
```

The above style will make all textboxes uppercase, you can change it to only apply to a specific textbook like this

```
<TextBox CharacterCasing="Upper" />
```

then when using the text entered, make it upper case.

Comment: @ noob This Properties is not for Windows Phone TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I tried this code and it worked.

```
void TxtPanno_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{

  TxtPanno.Text = TxtPanno.Text.ToUpper();
  TxtPanno.SelectionStart = TxtPanno.Text.Length;

}
```

Comment: If Jonas was the one who provided the answer, please accept **his** answer and delete your answer.  If it's really an answer of your own, then accept your answer.  It's important to flag the accepted answer to let users know there's a solution to your question.